# How to replace newlib's malloc

Tags: c, embedded, malloc, newlib

I'm using LPCXpresso with LPC1768. I'm trying to implement few memory pools. I have my old code that allows this, so I'm fine there. What I'm unable to do is to prevent newlib from using it's own malloc. There are few functions in newlib calling malloc. I dodged them all, except for _Csys_alloc, which is unfortunately called by _initio. Since malloc isn't weak, I can't simply replace it with my own implementation. So is there any other way to do it except for either modifying newlib and recompiling or writing my own _initio routine?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _Since malloc isn't weak_.  Please explain.  And, your root question seems to be how to avoid using _`Csys_alloc()`, although it is included in the definition of your init function.  The only way then would seem to be implementing your own _`initio()`

Comment: I think OP means `malloc` is not a weakly-defined symbol, so it's not possible to write a custom `malloc` and have the linker use that instead of the default `malloc`

Comment: "malloc isn't weak" means "malloc isn't a weak symbol".

Since _Csys_alloc() calls malloc, I want to replace malloc, not _Csys_alloc. _Csys_alloc is fine as long as it calls mine implementation.

And yes, I'm afraid replacing _initio() is the only way, but that's precisely what I want to avoid, thus the question. If an answer is "you can't do with newlib" (or redlib or newlib-nano), then I'll replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps simplest to let Newlib use its malloc as it wants and implement _sbrk() to limit its use and location to a static pool sized to just what is needed for library initialisation, then override malloc() for use in your own code - the linker will only link to standard library symbols if not previously found in another library of object code.